# Iterating over values in a csv file and creating directories

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with a structure like this:
[image]

I need to go through its rows and create a folder called as a column value "worker_id" with a file with a column value "audio_id" where there is text with a column value "text".
There is my code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('ya/audio_dataset/df.csv')
print(df.items())
print(df.head())
path0 = "1"

for text, audio_id, worker_id, task_id, path in df.items():
    path1 = path0 + worker_id
    if not (os.path.exists(path1)):
        try:
            os.mkdir(path1)
        except OSError:
            print("Создать директорию %s не удалось" % path1)
        else:
            print("Успешно создана директория %s " % path1)

    path2 = path1 + '/' + task_id

    if not (os.path.exists(path2)):
        try:
            os.mkdir(path2)
        except OSError:
            print("Создать директорию %s не удалось" % path2)
        else:
            print("Успешно создана директория %s " % path2)

    path3 = path2 + '/' + audio_id
    my_file = open("path3" + ".txt", "w+")
    my_file.write("text")
    my_file.close()

    os.rename('ya/audio-dataset/' + path, path3 + ".wav")
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/dip/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    for text, audio_id, worker_id, task_id, path in df.items():
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 2)
```

Comment: `df.items()` iterates over (columns, series), perhaps you wanted to use `df.iterrows()`

Comment: Actually `df.itertuples` is exactly what you want :)

Comment: @KarthikNayak with `df.itertuples` I am getting `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 5) ` :(

Comment: That is correct, isn't it? There are 11 columns, you're trying to unpack it into 5 columns.

Comment: @KarthikNayak Thank you, I figured it out!

Comment: Is the question solved then? ;)

Comment: @Florian Fasmeyer yes!